# Angular - Function Call in SVG

Tags: angular, svg

I am creating an Angular app and I want to display the values from one of the functions, *average*, I've written.

```
<svg *ngFor="let item of items;" width="500" height="75">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" [attr.fill]="item.color" />
  <text x="100" y="50">"average(item.count)"% {{item.name}}</text>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to get the actual value of the average function call within svg text?

If not, could someone point me in the right direction as to where I can look to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: @yurzui I did not.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use interpolation like:

```html
<text x="100" y="50">{{ average(item.count) }}% {{item.name}}</text>
```

but keep in mind that your average function will be executed on every change detection cycle. So maybe it's worth to prepare data for that.